# What is the difference between `%in%` and `==`?

Tags: r

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:10, time = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 0.5, 0.5, 
1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("x", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


df[df$time %in% c(0.5, 3), ]
##     x time
## 1   1  0.5
## 2   2  0.5
## 5   5  3.0
## 6   6  0.5
## 7   7  0.5
## 10 10  3.0

df[df$time == c(0.5, 3), ]
##     x time
## 1   1  0.5
## 7   7  0.5
## 10 10  3.0
```

What is the difference between `%in%` and `==` here?

Comment: See `?'=='` and `?'%in%'` in R

Comment: you might be interested in [video number #033](http://www.twotorials.com/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is vector recycling.

Your first line does exactly what you'd expect. It checks what elements of `df$time` are in `c(0.5, 3)` and returns the values which are.

Your second line is trickier. It's actually equivalent to

```
df[df$time == rep(c(0.5,3), length.out=nrow(df)),]
```

To see this, let's see what happens if use a vector `rep(0.5, 10)`:

```
rep(0.5, 10) == c(0.5, 3)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

See how it returns every odd value. Essentially it's matching 0.5 to the vector `c(0.5, 3, 0.5, 3, 0.5...)`

You can manipulate a vector to produce no matches this way. Take the vector: `rep(c(3, 0.5), 5)`:

```
rep(c(3, 0.5), 5) == c(0.5, 3)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

They're all `FALSE`; you are matching every 0.5 with 3 and vice versa.

Comment: get it always use `%in%` unless I am comparing one unique value OR actually intending to use recycling, very clear thanks +

Comment: @user1320502 Actually, there are some advantages to using %in% even when you have one value. Try `x <- c(1:5, rep(NA, 3)); x[x==3]` and compare that to `x[x%in%3]`.

Answer (score 15):

In

```
df$time == c(0.5,3)
```

the `c(0.5,3)` first gets broadcast to the shape of `df$time`, i.e. `c(0.5,3,0.5,3,0.5,3,0.5,3,0.5,3)`. Then the two vectors are compared element-by-element.

On the other hand,

```
df$time %in% c(0.5,3)
```

checks whether each element of `df$time` belongs to the set `{0.5, 3}`.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old thread, but I haven't seen this answer anywhere and it might be relevant for some people.

Another difference between the two is handling of NAs (missing values).

```
NA == NA
[1] NA
NA %in% c(NA)
[1] TRUE
```