# When selecting multiple inputs in a shiny app, why does the error depend on the order that the inputs were selected?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard document with `runtime: shiny` (*I posted the app here https://arie.shinyapps.io/reproducible_example/ and embedded the code, but wanted to put the code below as well in case the app exceeds its allotted usage on shinyapps.io*):

`---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    source_code: embed
---`

Given the following example data set:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(name = c("peter", "paul", "mary"), 
         value = c(1:3))
```
````

I want to be able to make multiple selections from the following user interface:

````
Column {data-width=250, .sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

# creates interface
selectInput("name_input", label = "Name", choices = df$name,
        selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)

```
````

and have a ggplot "react" to the selections. So I make a reactive data set:

````
```{r}
# reactive data
df_reactive <- reactive(df[df$name == input$name_input,])

```
````

and create the following plot:

````
Column {data-width=750}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderPlot(
 ggplot(df_reactive(), aes(x = input$name_input, y = value) ) +
  geom_col()
 )
```
````

Now, when I `Run Document` and select first `peter`, then `paul`, and then `mary`, the plot reacts exactly as expected: It adds a bar each time a name is added. The problem occurs when I, for example, first select `paul` and then `peter`, which throws the error `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): x, y`.

The error makes sense to me in the context of a static chart, but I am confused about why the order of selecting the names should matter and how it can be resolved.

Comment: shouldnt `df_reactive <- reactive(df[df$name == input$name_input,])` be replaced by `df_reactive <- reactive(df[df$name %in% input$name_input,])`?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helped! I will post it as an answer then,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within:

```
df_reactive <- reactive(df[df$name == input$name_input,])
```

If `length(input$name_input)` is < 3 you will try to compare two arrays of different length. R will throw an error and it is also not the test you actually want to perform. 
As I see it, you want to test for each element in `df$name` if it is included in `input$name_input`.  Luckily there is a shortcut for that in R, so you wont have to use a for loop or `sapply()`,...

Like I wrote in the comments: `df_reactive <- reactive(df[df$name %in% input$name_input,])` will work as well.

For more details concerning the notation, i would refer to an existing answer as the answer would become more of a duplicate then. 
The difference between `==` and `%in%` is explained here:
[difference between `%in%` VS `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358006/difference-between-in-vs)