# How to avoid code duplication in R

Tags: r

I've been using R for a while now, but find myself using those things over and over again. I guess there must be an easier way than to write:

```
filtered <- names(table(col))[!match.something(names(table(col)))]
```

Where match.something returns an T/F-list.

Of course I could do the following to make it more concise and remove some duplication:

```
x <- names(table(col))
filtered <- x[!match.something(x)]
```

But it still feels like there should be a different/easier way to select like this. Something like subset(x, fun), to avoid having to type "x" twice. Which function am I looking for?

Example:

```
> col <- c("AA", "AA", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AG")
> x <- names(table(col))
> x[match.bases(x)]
[1] "AA" "GG"
```

This is the function I'm using right now:

```
BASES = c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")

match.bases <- function(df) {
  df %in% BASES
}
```

Comment: You probably want `dplyr::select`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `select(x, match.bases)` but got: Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character". filter doesn't seem to work either. I probably should start with an dplyr tutorial to get there?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is `col`, why use `table`? Could you post a complete example?

Comment: Related: [*Difference between `%in%` and `==`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358006/difference-between-in-and)

Comment: Perhaps your `match.bases` function is much more complicated, but just seeing this example I would suggest something like `intersect(x, c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT"))` - not only shorter, but also much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for giving an alternative, I was also using the `match.bases` for something like `data[!match.bases(data)] <- NA` but it might make sense to define a variable like `BASES` and use that in both cases.

Comment: @AkselA I extended my example, probably there is a better way to aggregate the values like I'm doing with table/names. Which is only a side problem, though.
@Jaap thanks, I rewrote my match.bases function. I wrote that quite a while ago, that's why I weren't using `%in%` yet.

Comment: There's also no need for `return()`. In the real data is `col` the column names of a data.frame or something similar?

Comment: col is a column of a data frame, containing SNP data produced by genetic markers (don't ask me about details, I'm programming it for my wife who is doing the actual interpretation).

Comment: If you have defined match.bases function, why don't go further and define other subsets functions to be reused ? e.g. something like `only.bases <- function(df){ df[match.bases(df)] }` and `allexcept.bases <- function(df){ df[!match.bases(df)] }`

Comment: Ok, so you want to return rows where `dtf$col %in% c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")` is `TRUE`?

Comment: In this example yes, and I want to avoid having to type "dtf$col" more than once. I usually see myself writing a condition like `dtf$col %in% c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")` and then surrounding it with `dtf$col[ ... ]` to get the actual data. Which is even more cumbersome if `dft$col` is a variable with a longer name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you want `purrr::keep` which will only keep elements that satisfy a predicate.

```
purrr::keep(x, match.bases)
# [1] "AA" "GG"
```

## Edit

As, digEmAll commented, the base R equivalent is `Filter(match.bases, x)`.

Comment: That does the job, however I was hoping for something that doesn't need an external library. Can this be done with something more basic or at least a library that is more widespread (e.g. I haven't heard of purrr before, but have encountered dplyr quite often)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the goal is to subset rows based on values in `col`.
I don't know if there is a more concise way to do it in base R.

```
col <- c("AA", "AA", "GC", "TG", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AG")
dtf <- data.frame(col, val=1:8)

dtf[dtf$col %in% c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT"),]

# or using your function
dtf[match.bases(dtf$col),]

#   col val
# 1  AA   1
# 2  AA   2
# 5  GG   5
# 6  GG   6
# 7  AA   7
```

Although if you only want to keep the subset `val`, it can be done like this. No repeating of names.

```
with(dtf, val[col %in% c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")])

# or using your function
with(dtf, val[match.bases(col)])

# 1 2 5 6 7
```

Also, if you want a function like `subset(x, FUN)`, you can just make one:

```
sbst <- function(x, FUN, ...) {
    x[FUN(x, ...)]
}

sbst(x, match.bases)
# "AA" "GG"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use directly the names to retrieve the data from a `table` object and do not need your `match` function at all:

```
col   <- c("AA", "AA", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AG")
bases <- c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")
table(col)[bases]
```

And if you want to prevent having `NA`s, you may use `intersect`:

```
col   <- c("AA", "AA", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AG")
bases <- c("AA", "GG", "CC", "TT")
table(col)[intersect(col, bases)]
```