# Error at filtering is deleting too many rows

Tags: r

The following message deletes almost all my rows, what is happening?

This is the code:

```
table <- table%>%filter(ESTADO == c('ACTIVA','ACTIVO','TARJETA NUEVA','NORMAL','DESEMBOLSADO','REESTRUCTURADO','N'))
```

This is the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(ESTADO, c("ACTIVA", "ACTIVO", "TARJETA NUEVA", "NORMAL",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: instead of using `==`, use `%in%`.  Possible duplicate of [Difference between \`%in%\` and \`==\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358006/difference-between-in-and)

Comment: Great insight! Thanks!